# GridLayoutManager with EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener recylerView.addOnScrollListener automatically scrolling in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, onscrolllistener

```
  public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 0; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 0;

    private GridLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
      this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
      visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
      totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
      firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
      Log.i("ProdctOffer load", mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + "//" + ProductList.size() + "//" + loading);
      if (mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == ProductList.size() - 1 && loading) {
        //bottom of list!
        current_page++;
        onLoadMore(current_page);
      }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
  }
```

Comment: Please write your question

Comment: what is your question? and what are your requirement.

Comment: onLoadMore automatically calling